# Can a few employees share the same inbox in Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-email

I am administrator for a shop. We have a few employees but we use one email address for customers, `shop@example.com`

It would be nice to organize this in some way so that the employees can have their own email accounts, but still answer on emails that is received on the shops common email.

How to organize this in Gmail for Google Apps (the company edition of Gmail)? Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using email group is one option but if you want to be able to Send As you might need a shared mailbox. I'm not completely sure but I don't think you can configure Send As from a group.

If you are using Premier edition, you can create a shared mailbox and then give each user access to that account. They will be able to then open that mailbox from their existing mailbox via a dropdown that appears next to their email address. In that mailbox they can read and response from that mailbox.

You could also configure a new mailbox and forward messages either to a group or each user with filters. Then you'd need to configure Send As on each users mailbox.

Lots of options.

Comment: Using "Send As" is the best solution I've found so far too.

Answer (score 1):

You can make shop@example.com a group that is made up of any set of other email addresses.  I have this setup in exactly this way for my contact email address.

[Google documentation](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33329)

Comment: For a quick guide, it should be the third tab from the left in your apps management dashboard, called Groups. Just create a new group, and add the employees.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do to acieve this is to have each of your staff connect into the same Gmail account via IMAP. That way they will all be able to see what is read and what have been replied to.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use for a **collaborative inbox**, which is a supported feature in G Suite (Google Apps). In short, it is an email group (with its own address) with a GUI, that all group members can access.

The collaborative inbox has features to track which messages are being worked on by who, so it works a bit like a support ticket system.

See [Google's Documentation: Use a group as a collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en)